# обтекание изображения текстом в EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-layout, customview

Справа от ImageView в EditText должен вводиться текст. Если вдруг окажется что текст заполнил все пространство справа от ImageView, нужно чтобы текст продолжал вводиться под ImageView начиная от самого (левого) края экрана устройства. Схематически это представлено на прикрепленном рисунке. 
[image: пример]

Сразу скажу что [подобный вариант](http://dev.androidteam.ru/snippets/textview/leadingmarginspan2) чудесно работает с TextView, но не хочет сотрудничать с EditText. Прошу не оставаться равнодушными и подсказать хотя бы направление решения моей проблемы.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, однако то, что вы хотите сделать без сложных костылей не получится. Если это не очень существенно, проще использовать один EditText сразу под картинкой или рядом с ней. Так же, конечно, интересно увидеть пример реализации такого обтекания :)

Comment: А в чем выражается, что этот вариант не хочет сотрудничать с TextView ? EditText собственно наследник TextView и в нем не так уж много изменено...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После нескольких экспериментов и изучения EditText/TextView оказалось, что в TextView (в котором собственно и задано все необходимое для редактирования текста) есть ошибки (или недоделки) из-за которых он при отрисовке курсора и выделения не принимает во внимание span текста.

В результате текст в EditText при использовании LeadingMarginSpan отрисовывается правильно, а выделение и курсор ведут себя так, как будто текст занимает прямоугольник (за исключением первой строки).

Чтобы это реализовать надо делать свой кастомный TextView и править в нем баги доделывать недоделки. Учитывая, что TextView содержит порядка 10000 строк кода это будет непросто.